# Ildasm Ctrl + M (Metadata)

Tags: ildasm

I've opened assembly created by me named `CarLibrary.dll` with `ildasm.exe`, but when I try to open it's metadata with shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (or by choosing it from the main menu) the program is being closed instead of launching it.

This does work when I try to open let's say `mscorlib.dll`.

Why is that happening?
I am using MS VS .NET 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

If you are on Windows 7, try using ildasm in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

I believe this has to do with the .Net framework version of your assembly and the version of ildasm.

Answer (score 0):

i'm puzzled by this problem,I've finally found the path which the assembly you want to opened  cannot include non-English character. PLS put the assembly in English character path.try it!